# How to delete table (class) from my parse.com account

Tags: parse-platform

Since there is no parse.com API to delete a class, how should one delete a class in one call?  the recommended way is to delete row by row and then the class is left empty but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/' + ___TABLE_NAME___,
    body: '{"_ApplicationId":"___APP_ID___","_MasterKey":"___MASTER_KEY___","_ClientVersion":"browser","_method":"DELETE"}',
    headers: {
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Origin': 'https://www.parse.com',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
        'Host': 'api.parse.com',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Referer': 'https://www.parse.com/apps/COLLECTION_NAME/collections',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': '163'
    }
};

request(options, function(r,o,t) {
    callback();
})
```